# Limit of Image URL's length in Internet Explorer

Tags: http, internet-explorer, browser, max, limit

I read some topics about limit of URL in Internet Explorer at:

- [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/417184)
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208427

Is this limit (2083 characters) also applied for 'src' attribute of img tag?

I guessed the answer is “Yes”, but my testing shows a different result. I created a test HTML page which contains an image with src's length is about 4000 character and I see the request is still trafficked successfully via Fiddler without any truncation. This works in Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11. So looks like this limit is not applied for this case?

Sample code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="http://somehost.com/x=about-4000-char-url..." />
</body>
</html>
```

Sample code which uses JavaScript to create image:

```
var url = 'http://somehost.com/x=about-4000-char-url...';
var img = new Image;
img.src = url;
window.customImage = img;
```